# error when calling input parameter in survival function

Tags: shiny

There is something wrong when calling the input in my app `'x' must be numeric`. Does anyone see what is wrong?
I think the error relates to `input$MicroRNA`

```
structure(list(hsa_miR_524_5p = c(-1.25502104562923, -1.27256722242831, 
-1.33134902421063, -1.1390337316217, -1.14257242781803), hsa_miR_548aq_5p = c(-1.25502104562923, 
-1.27256722242831, -1.33134902421063, -1.1390337316217, -1.14257242781803
), hsa_miR_6778_5p = c(-1.25502104562923, -1.27256722242831, 
-1.33134902421063, -1.1390337316217, -1.14257242781803), hsa_miR_6812_5p = c(-1.25502104562923, 
-1.27256722242831, -1.33134902421063, -1.1390337316217, -1.14257242781803
), hsa_miR_3122 = c(-1.25502104562923, -1.27256722242831, -1.33134902421063, 
-1.1390337316217, -1.14257242781803), hsa_miR_3923 = c(-1.25502104562923, 
-1.27256722242831, -1.33134902421063, -1.1390337316217, -1.14257242781803
), hsa_miR_4465 = c(-1.25502104562923, -1.27256722242831, -1.33134902421063, 
-1.1390337316217, -1.14257242781803), hsa_miR_4641 = c(-1.25502104562923, 
-1.27256722242831, -1.33134902421063, -1.1390337316217, -1.14257242781803
), TimeDiff = c(71.0416666666667, 601.958333333333, 1130, 1393, 
117.041666666667), Status = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), row.names = c("86", 
"175", "217", "394", "444"), class = "data.frame")

ui <- fluidPage(
    selectInput("MicroRNA", "miRNA", choices = unique(colnames(df.miRNA.cpm.t))),
    plotOutput("myplot"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    


    output$myplot <- renderPlot({
       
        fitSurv <- survfit(Surv(ss.survival.shiny.miRNA$TimeDiff, ss.survival.shiny.miRNA$Status) ~ paste(cut(input$MicroRNA   , quantile(input$MicroRNA   , probs = c(0, 0.8)), include.lowest=T)), data = as.data.frame((df.miRNA.cpm.t)))
        
        
        ggsurvplot(fitSurv ,title="", xlab="Time (Yrs)", ylab="Survival prbability",
                   font.main = 8,
                   font.x =  8,
                   font.y = 8,
                   font.tickslab = 8,
                   font.legend=8,
                   pval.size = 3,
                   pval.coord = c(1000,1),
                   size=0.4,
                   legend = "right",
                   censor.size=2,
                   break.time.by = 365,
                   pval =T,#"p=0.003",#"p=0.41",
                   #xscale=365,
                   #palette = c("#E7B800", "#2E9FDF"),
                   #ggtheme = theme_bw(),
                   risk.table = F,
                   xscale=365.25,
                   xlim=c(0,7*365))
           
        
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

'x' must be numeric

Comment: Your variable name `ss.survival.shiny.miRNA$TimeDiff` might be an issue.  Please use simpler names in the function.

Comment: No, its not that. Its related to the part within the cut-function.

Comment: You have a few issues. All your variables have character values.  You need to convert them to numeric.  Next you have 6 records in `TimeDiff`, while 5 records in the `input$MicroRNA` variable. Also, it might be best to have all variables in one dataframe.

Comment: Updated my questions. Now, both the clincal data and the expression data is in the input matrix.